# Rotation and translation are reversed

Tags: opengl, 3d

I am trying to get nice rotation for objects in 3D space.

Everything looks pretty good, except my rotation movements are reversed.

I'll illustrate my problem with couple of screenshots. Note, that green axis - Y, red axis - X and blue - Z.

If I drag cursor from point A to point B. I am expecting to get rotation as shown on with red arrow, but in fact - model is rotating in as shown with green arrow.

[image]

But if I align geometry to point with Y axis (green) down cursor movements from point A to point B gives result as it was expected. Model is rotating as shown with red arrow.

[image]

Same situation I have with vertical rotation.

I am drawing geometry with shaders. My matrices set-ups before render looks like:

```
modelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;

viewMatrix =
        Matrix4.CreateRotationY(_xRot) * // just input from mouse movements
        Matrix4.CreateRotationX(_yRot) * // just input from mouse movements
        Matrix4.CreateScale(_scale);     // just input from mouse movements

projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(width, heigth, 10000f, -10000f);
```

Rotation from mouse input:

```
private void glControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        var dx = (e.X - _previousCursorPosition.X) / (float)Width;
        var dy = (e.Y - _previousCursorPosition.Y) / (float)Height;


        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.None)
        {
            _xrot += dx * RotationSensititivity;
            _yrot += dy * RotationSensititivity;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no 'camera' in OpenGL. Rather than transforming a camera to a certain position and orientation, you transform the _entire world_ by the opposite of your 'camera's transformation.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two thanks, I've edited my question

Comment: Based on the illustrations, you're using a left-handed coordinate system. While that's perfectly legal, you'll have to be careful about how you build your transformation matrices. They will have to look slightly different from the way they would in a standard right-handed coordinate system.

Comment: In any case, there are a number of subtle ways the orientation can end up going the opposite direction. Mouse input uses a coordinate system where the y goes from top to bottom on most systems, while OpenGL uses bottom to top. OpenGL assumes that transformation matrices are column major, so you could have them transposed. Or the rotation matrices might just be wrong.